# jsf & facelets: many <ui:remove> tags in production enviroment: performance?

Tags: facelets, jsf-2.3

i am currently re-working some jsf-pages of a larger project and locate a lot of stuff surrounded by

```
<ui:remove>codes and comments...</ui:remove>
```

stuff. many parts are not "normal comments", but large code fragments with unknown purpose.

i wonder if the massive presence of this tag can be a performance issue and if so: is there something that we can include in the build-process to remove all that useless content in production enviroments?

thanks in advance!